# Find all instances where a user has been explicitly granted permissions on an object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions

Is it possible to generate the list of objects a user has been given explicit access to, for a certain user?

I'd like to see a list of all the items a user has explicit permissions for, excluding any permissions inherited through roles etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the `sys.database_permissions` DMV, which contains all granted and denied permissions.

The `major_id` will point to the `object_id` in `sys.objects`, the `minor_id` points to the `column_id` in `sys.columns` (if applicable).

The `grantee_principal_id` and `grantor_principal_id` columns point to the granted and granting user ID respectively, which you can find in `sys.database_principals`.

Remember that permissions can be assigned not just to users, but also to server or database roles, which the user can inherit. Also, granted and denied permissions can conflict, in which case the more restrictive of the two rules applies.

I wrote a [blog series](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/07/20/the-sql-server-security-model-part-1/) a while back, which goes into more details on permissions.